# AWS Lambda function never trigger the on 'data' function of socket stream (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, stream, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the wrapper wkhtmltoimage of nodejs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltoimage), but the event on 'data' is never triggered, here is my current code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {


    process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];
    const nodeStream = require('stream');

    const wkhtmltoimage = require('wkhtmltoimage').setCommand(__dirname + '/wkhtmltoimage');
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        try {

            const renderUrl = event["queryStringParameters"]['url'];    
            console.log('renderUrl: ', renderUrl);

            const socket = wkhtmltoimage.generate(renderUrl);
            const passThroughStream = new nodeStream.PassThrough();
            socket.setEncoding('binary');

            socket.pipe(passThroughStream);

            let body = '';
            passThroughStream.on('data', function(chunk) {                
                console.log('On data');   //This line is never called
                body += chunk;
            });            

            passThroughStream.on('end', function() {
                console.log('On end');
                resolve(body);            
            });


        } catch (error){
            console.log("Error: "  , error);
            reject(error);
        }  
    })
    .then(value => { callback(null,value); })
    .catch(error => { console.log('catch error'); callback(error); });      
}
```

I am deploying the binary wkhtmltoimage inside the zip, I made sure to run chmod 755 on all files inside the zip folder, I also added the path on the function startup, what is wrong here?

If I run this function locally (like showing below), I get the desired image as output:

```
exports.handler({queryStringParameters:{url:'https://www.google.com'}}, null, function(err, value){
    require("fs").writeFile("out__3.png", value, 'binary', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

EDIT: I also tried using the variable socket instead of the passThroughStream.

Comment: Are you sure that the `wkhtmltoimage` binary is properly installed and called on the Lambda? Maybe the `setCommand` is not pointing to the right file.

Comment: i check that file exists using require("fs").existsSync('./wkhtmltoimage') , so I suppose that's not the problem

Comment: Does it have the right permission for the node process to call it? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yes I did, chmod 755 on the file and no errors on the console.log, its weird

Comment: And when you're trying locally with the real URL, is it working?

Comment: The problem was on the binary itself, I was using a bad binary from a different OS version, and to work on AWS I had to use a specific one that I got from a repo online